# Mysql: select timestamps between 22th of january and 3rd of february, any year

Tags: mysql, date, select

I need to compare sales in a period of days, across several years in my databases.

So I need to select rows with a timestamp that is in the range 22th january to 3rd february. The year can be anything.

How to do this?

example table sales:

```
timestamp             sales_amount
2012-01-22 16:28:01   78
2012-10-11 16:28:06   90
2014-02-01 16:28:06   27
```

Select should get row 1 and 3, and exclude row 2 since its not between the specified days.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE DAYOFYEAR(`the_date_column`) BETWEEN 9 AND 34
```

This does not always work, but works for your required date range, because `DAYOFYEAR` of any date in that range is always fixed regardless of year.

Answer (score 0):

As a general solution, you can play the trick, that you set the year to a specific one. For example:

```
select * from t
where str_to_date(date_format(timestamp, '1970-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
   between '1970-01-22 00:00:00' and '1970-02-03 23:59:59';
```